# NET CLI tool contains deps.json with development dependency (GitVersion.MsBuild)

Tags: .net, .net-core, nuget, nuget-package, gitversion

I'm working on a .NET cli tool. The created nuget package contains a deps.json. This deps.json file contains entries for all referenced nuget packages.
After installing the tool `dotnet tool install..` I can not run the tool `dotnet tool run` because an assembly listed in the deps.json file is missing

```
      An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (xxxx.deps.json) was not found:
package: 'Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents', version: '4.7.0'
path: 'runtimes/win/lib/netcoreapp3.0/Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.dll'
```

The package contains a `runtimes/win/lib/netcoreapp3.0` folder but not `Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.dll`

[image]

**The Problem seems to be the entries in deps.json for `GitVersion.MsBuild`. Because if I either remove this dependency or delete deps.json the application works as expected.**

- Why is a dev dependency `<PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>` included in deps.json?
- How can i exclude deps.json from package and is this a good idea?

csprj:

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
        <PackAsTool>true</PackAsTool>
        <IncludeBuildOutput>false</IncludeBuildOutput>
        <PackageId>xxxxxxx</PackageId>
        <ToolCommandName>xxxxx</ToolCommandName>
        <PackageOutputPath>..\..\artifacts</PackageOutputPath>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="CommandLineParser" Version="2.8.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="GitVersion.MsBuild" Version="5.6.6">
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
      <PackageReference Include="NuGet.ProjectModel" Version="5.8.1" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

deps.json snippet:

```
  "GitVersion.MsBuild/5.6.6": {
    "dependencies": {
      "Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core": "16.8.0"
    }
  },

  // snipp..

  "Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents/4.7.0": {
    "dependencies": {
      "Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms": "3.1.0"
    },
    "runtimeTargets": {
      "runtimes/win/lib/netcoreapp3.0/Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.dll": {
        "rid": "win",
        "assetType": "runtime",
        "assemblyVersion": "4.0.2.0",
        "fileVersion": "4.700.19.56404"
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The deps.json contains all dev dependencies and does not make sense for NET tools.
The solution was to disable the generation of the deps.json file completely.

```
        <GenerateDependencyFile>false</GenerateDependencyFile>
```